# Django AssertTemplateUsed test fails since Upgrade to Django 1.8

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-templates

Since updating from Django 1.7.x to Django 1.8.x, my tests fail when checking for the right template. I'm using a ResearchFactory:

```
class AdminUnitTest(TestCase):
    """Sets up the testing environment for an admin"""

    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username="cj123",
            email="chuck.jones@acme.edu",
            password="xxx",
            first_name="Chuck",
            last_name="Jones"
        )
        admin = Staff.objects.create(user=user, role='admin')
        self.user = user
```

The actual test then looks like this:

```
class YearViewTest(AdminUnitTest):
    def test_year_view_uses_right_template(self):
        request = self.factory.get('/year_view/all')
        request.user = self.user
        response = year_view(request, 'all')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'year_view.html')
```

This approach worked perfectly fine, until the update to 1.8. Since then I get the following error:

```
ValueError: assertTemplateUsed() and assertTemplateNotUsed() are only usable on responses fetched using the Django test Client.
```

In Django's source code (http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/django/test/testcases.html) I can only find this condition raising the error I get:

```
if template_name is not None and response is not None and not hasattr(response, 'templates'):
    raise ValueError(
            "assertTemplateUsed() and assertTemplateNotUsed() are only "
            "usable on responses fetched using the Django test Client."
        )
```

I struggle to see where my error there is. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems quite clear: you can only use that assertion on responses fetched via the test client. You're not using that, you're canning the view directly.

You should use the client anyway: it would simplify your test considerably. It would just become:

```
def test_year_view_uses_right_template(self):
    self.client.login('cj123', 'xxx')
    response = self.client.get('/year_view/all')
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'year_view.html')
```

Comment: I realised that your code was faking a login; I've added an explicit call to the client's login method. You could put that in your setUp method if it needs to be done everywhere.

Comment: Thanks - that explains it. Your code is far more straight forward and obvious - no idea what tutorial I found my difficult version in.